# How to check for an event within a timeframe?

Tags: c, loops, time, arduino

*edit* I just want to say thank you to whoever downvoted this question for no reason, have a good day.

--

I have an Arduino Uno and trying to program a locking mechanism using knocks (as per the examples book). However I want to insert a time limit when checking for knocks, so something like this :

```
void loop(){

  if two knocks are sensed in less than a second

     do something

  else reset 

}
```

OR

```
void loop(){

  if knock is sensed

     reset value after 1 second  // to eliminate error

   else if two knocks are sensed in less than a second

     do something

}
```

Delays won't work here, and I thought of having int variables that can be added within if loops, but not sure how to exactly implement it. Maybe a nested for loop ?

Any ideas ?

---

I added my code in case that helps get an idea of what I'm doing

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myServo;

const int piezo = A4;



// boolean locked = false; //might remove later ?

int numberOfKnocks = 0;



void setup (){

  myServo.attach(2);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  //myServo.write(10);

  //delay(1000);

  myServo.write(25);

  numberOfKnocks = 0;

  delay(2000);

  Serial.println("done");



}

int knockVal = 0;

void loop(){

  knockVal = analogRead(piezo);

  Serial.print("Knock value is ");

  Serial.println(knockVal);



  if(numberOfKnocks < 2 && knockVal > 2){

  //  if(checkForKnock(knockVal) == true){

      numberOfKnocks++;

      Serial.print(2-numberOfKnocks);

      Serial.println("  number of knocks to go");

//    }

  }

  else if(numberOfKnocks >=2){

    myServo.write(10);

    delay(1000);

    myServo.write(25);

    //knockVal=0;

    Serial.println("locking");

    numberOfKnocks=0;

   delay(2000);

  }

}
```

Managed to get it to work thanks to user who answered me below, code becomes :

```
int temp=0;
if (knockVal > 2){

elapsedTime = millis() - timestamp;

Serial.print( "Time since the last knock " );

Serial.print( elapsedTime );

Serial.println( " msec" );

timestamp = millis();

delay(200);

temp=1;

}

if (elapsedTime < 300 && temp==1){

Serial.println( "SUCCESS ");

myServo.write(10);

delay(1000);

myServo.write(25);

//knockVal=0;

Serial.println("locking");

numberOfKnocks=0;

delay(2000);

temp=0;
```

}

---

3 Knocks code done !

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;
const int piezo = A4;
//int numberOfKnocks = 0;
void setup (){
  myServo.attach(2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.write(25);
//  numberOfKnocks = 0;
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Initilization Complete");
}
unsigned long timestamp = 0; // FOR TIMER
unsigned long timestamp2 = 0;
int knockVal = 0;
unsigned long elapsedTime;
int elapsedTime2;
int temp = 0;
void loop(){
  knockVal = analogRead(piezo);
// Serial.print("Knock value is ");
// Serial.println(knockVal);

  if (knockVal > 2){
    elapsedTime = millis() - timestamp;
    Serial.print( "Time since the last knock " );
    Serial.print( elapsedTime );
    Serial.println( " ms" );
    elapsedTime2 = (millis() - timestamp2);
    timestamp = millis();
    timestamp2= (millis() - elapsedTime) ;

    delay(200);
    temp=1;
//    Serial.print( "elapsedTime2 " );
//    Serial.print( elapsedTime2 );
//    Serial.println( " ms" );
  }
  if (elapsedTime2 < 500 && temp==1){


    Serial.println("Toggling Switch");
    myServo.write(10);
    delay(1000);
    myServo.write(25);
    //numberOfKnocks=0;
   delay(500);
   Serial.println( "SUCCESS ");
    temp=0;
}
}

//  if(numberOfKnocks < 2 && knockVal > 2){
//   if(checkForKnock(knockVal) == true){
//      numberOfKnocks++;
//      Serial.print(2-numberOfKnocks);
//      Serial.println("  number of knocks to go");
//    }
//  }
//  else if(numberOfKnocks >=2){
//    myServo.write(10);
//    delay(1000);
//    myServo.write(25);
//    //knockVal=0;
//    Serial.println("locking");
//    numberOfKnocks=0;
//   delay(2000);
//  }
//}

//boolean checkForKnock(int value){ //function
//  if(value >= 1){
//    Serial.print("Check for Knock value is  ");
//    Serial.println(value);
//    return true;
//  }
//  if(value <1){
//    return false;
//  }
//}
```

Comment: You need to search  for the timers that are provided and study how to operate them.

Comment: Yeah, like millis().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows how to use the `millis()` function to determine the time between two events. Each time the piezo returns a value greater than 2, the elapsed time is displayed, and the timestamp is updated.

```
unsigned long timestamp = 0;

void loop()
{
    int piezoValue;
    unsigned long elapsedTime;

    piezoValue = analogRead(piezo);

    if ( piezoValue > 2 )
    {
        // compute the time (in milliseconds) since the last knock
        elapsedTime = millis() - timestamp;

        Serial.print( "Time since the last knock " );
        Serial.print( elapsedTime );
        Serial.println( " msec" );

        // store the current time 
        timestamp = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you add comments to the lines above just to get a better understanding how the code works ?

Comment: @NLed I've added a couple comments. Let me know if there is a particular line that you're interested in.

Comment: You can see in my code that it there is less than 2 knocks then go into the IF loop and increment the value. I will replace this whole IF statement with a timed function. So from your code, how would it know the time of the first knock ? I'm understanding that the formula calculates the time since the last knock only ?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate this with my code and will reply back. I think i got it.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Worked like a charm :D

Comment: Just to get things straight, millis() starts a count when the micro controller turns on right ? You first subtract time stamp which does nothing, but only gets a value after the first knock. So the second time the loop is entered, the subtraction gives a value from which 'second - first' knocks, and hence we get the difference. Is this correct ?

Comment: @NLed Yes, that is all correct. The first subtraction will be the time from when the controller turned on until the first knock. Usually, that will be more than 1 second, so you don't need to do anything about it. But, if you want, you could handle the very first knock as a special case, and just update the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help. I wonder how this can be accommodated to only allow 3 knocks, rather than two consecutive ones. Can it be done using time only as your answer ? Or do we need to add a count in this case ?

Comment: @NLed To allow multiple knocks or specific patterns of knocks, you would need to keep an array of timestamps for all the previous knocks, and things start to get complicated.

Comment: I'm going to try and do that now !!

Comment: I've done it and updated question with result. However this only works for 3 knocks. I am sure there is a way to create a function that can adapt to any number of knocks the user wants.